# Android/Cordova: Where to add files?

Tags: android, cordova

I have successfully created a project with the cordova command line tool and I am able to import this project in the Android Development Toolkit as well as run it in the emulator.

Now, I see the example files in the folder "/www". When I change these files, build the project (using CIT) and run it in the emulator, I do not see the changes I made. I assume that I need to change other files or put them in another folder. The assets folder is empty besides a file that says that I need to delete the exclusion filters to see the files. Do I need to change the files in there?

???

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Do I need to change the files in there? : Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a cordova project has been created. It has a root  `/www` folder where all resources are eligible to be shared on the added platforms (which you intends to add)

You should modify here. though its possible to modify resources per platform. (read more [API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides))

Once any shared resource i.e. inside the main **www** folder are modified then you have to issue **cordova build** in order to reflect the changes in the corresponding platforms (which you have added)

You are unable to see the `assets` folder resources. Because by default it is **hidden**. Just select the project and go in properties and then remove the checks.

**Import existing Android project --> select project --> right click select properties --> Resource --> Resource filters.**

From the Exclude All , **remove both items.** This will show you resources inside `assets` folder.

Comment: AAhad, thanks for the clarification. Is it possible to add the cordova build command in the debug command of the ADT?

Comment: Hmm it may be or may be not possible. What you want to achieve. You can create separate build scripts and execute it based on the need